# How to call User::load with dependency injection

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I have code that worked, but I wanted to clean it up and use dependency injection. I'm working in a BlockBase that implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.

```
class DefaultBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {
```

I need to access some information from the user object. Right now I'm using Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface. This works fine, but doesn't give me all the information I was expecting. I have a contrib module adding a field to the user. I can access that field if I use User::load($id) however, I get the warning that...

> User::load calls should be avoided in Drupal classes, use dependency
>   injection instead

So I'm trying. And failing.

This code works...

```
$userIdx = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
$userx = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userIdx);
$countryx = $userx->country_iso_code_2;
```

But when I clean that up and do it the right way, I can't get that country_iso_code_2 information.

Here is the code I'm "trying" to work with...

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\country_selector\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'DefaultBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "default_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Country switcher"),
 * )
 */
class DefaultBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  protected $account;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, AccountProxyInterface $account) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->account = $account;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = [];

    $userIdx = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    $userx = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userIdx);
    $countryx = $userx->country_iso_code_2;

    $userId = $this->account->id();
    $country = $this->account->country_iso_code_2;
    .....
```

When I debug, I see that:

> $userx is Drupal\user\Entity\User
>
> $user is Drupal\core\Session\AccountProxy

So I get that I'm working with two different things. I just don't understand how I'm supposed to call something like User::load with dependency injection.

I hope that makes sense. Would love some advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use entity_type_manage to get the user storage. Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\country_selector\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserStorageInterface;
/**
 * Provides a 'DefaultBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "default_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Country switcher"),
 * )
 */
class DefaultBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  protected $account;
  protected $userStorage;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, AccountProxyInterface $account, UserStorageInterface $user_storage) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->account = $account;
    $this->userStorage = $user_storage;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('current_user'),
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function build() {
    $build = [];

    $userIdx = $this->$acount->id();
    $userx = $this->userStorage->load($userIdx);
    $countryx = $userx->country_iso_code_2;
    .....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That definitely helps. Thank you. I owe you a beer!

Comment: Line ```$userIdx = $this->$acount->id();``` should be ```$userIdx = $this->account->id();```